# Drawing a line on existing View

Tags: android

I have a linear layout consisting of few buttons. I want to draw lines (vertical, horizontal, tilted) connecting different buttons based on the values of these buttons.

Most examples I have gone through deal with creating a new View class and updating its onDraw method to draw the lines. Then they setContentView to an instance of this new View class.

But with the above approach I lose the other content on my screen. I want to keep all the buttons and their values intact and just draw a line over the buttons.

It would be great if someone could point me in the right direction.

Regards,
RG

Comment: *I lose the other content on my screen* - this can't happen if you call through the super implementation.

Comment: create a custom root level layout that extends RelativeLayout or LinearLayout or whatever ViewGroup and override its dispatchDraw method

Comment: Thanks a lot. Creating a  custom root level and overriding its dispatchDraw method worked for me.